# Limit and merge saving operations

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

**Use case:**
I want to automatically save data in the storage when a property of an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged changes. Therefore I subscribe to the PropertyChanged event and call a method that saves the object.

**Problem:**
It can be that a lot of properties change over a short period of time and that is a problem because the saving method is an I/O operation.

**My solution:**
Accumulate the save orders over a period of time in a singleton class and perform the saving operations for the last order.

**Code:**

```
internal sealed class AccumulatedSaver
{
    private readonly Queue<Tuple<string, object>> _saveOrders = new Queue<Tuple<string, object>>();
    private bool _busy = false;

    internal static AccumulatedSaver Instance { get; } = new AccumulatedSaver();

    internal async Task SaveToAppData<T>(T item, string fileName)
    {
        _saveOrders.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, object>(fileName,item));
        if (_busy)
        {
            return;
        }
        _busy = true;
        await Task.Run(async() => await Task.Delay(500));

        while (_saveOrders.Count > 0)
        {
            Tuple<string, object> saveOrder = _saveOrders.Dequeue();
            if (_saveOrders.All(o => o.Item1 != saveOrder.Item1))
            {
                await SaveHelper.TrySaveToAppData(saveOrder.Item2, saveOrder.Item1);
            }
        }
        _busy = false;
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is that a good idea to do that like that?
What can be made better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Alternative: Rx

Creating your own producer/consumer solution is not always easy and is one option but you could also use the tools that are already there. One such tool are the [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242981(v=vs.103).aspx) (NuGet-Package: `System.Reactive`). It can be very helpful in your scenario.

I requires two parties

- an observable and
- an observer

Your not yet real observables are the POCO objects that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can turn them into observables with helper factories that can *derive* an `IObservable` from the `PropertyChanged` event pattern.

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged, IObservable<EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>>
{
    private readonly IObservable<EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>> _observable;

    private string _name;

    public Person()
    {
        _observable =
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                    handler => PropertyChanged += handler,
                    handler => PropertyChanged -= handler
                );
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>> observer)
    {
        return _observable.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Now you only need a task to process a collection of them. You can create it in many different ways so here is just one of them. I created an observable from an array of persons that I `Merge` into a single observable that I want to *watch*. I'd like this to be processed either every ten items or every two seconds (there are also other options). Then each batch is processed with the `ForEachAsync` loop.

```
var persons = new[]
{
    new Person { Name = "John"},
    new Person { Name = "Tom" }
};

var savePersonBatchTask = 
    persons
        .Merge()        
        .Buffer(timeSpan: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), count: 10)
        .Where(batch => buffer.Count > 0)
        .ForEachAsync(batch =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"New batch arrived: {batch.Count}");
        });
```

You can test this simulation by creating another loop that modifies the person's name 27 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        person.Name = i.ToString();
    }
}

await savePersonBatchTask;
```

The output will look like this

```
New batch arrived: 10
New batch arrived: 10
New batch arrived: 10
New batch arrived: 10
New batch arrived: 10
New batch arrived: 4
```

There is a lot more it can do and all that is explained very nicely on [Introduction to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html).

---

#### Review

And I also have a couple of comments about your code...

> ```
> private readonly Queue<Tuple<string, object>> _saveOrders
> ```

You can simplify this and make it easier to use by using *strong* tuples with named properties. All you need is to throw away the `Tuple` type and let the compiler derive the tuple for you.

```
 private readonly Queue<(string FileName, object Item)> _saveOrders = ..;
```

later in code you also don't need it anymore

```
saveOrders.Enqueue((fileName,item));
```

Your `while` loop will become simpler too because tuples can be deconstructed into variables:

```
while (_saveOrders.Count > 0)
{
    var (fileName, item) = _saveOrders.Dequeue();
    if (_saveOrders.All(o => o.FileName != fileName))
    {
        await SaveHelper.TrySaveToAppData(fileName, item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem I see is no call to force the save.  You could have that in another method but you should not be repeating the save code.

Seems to me a producer consumer like [BackGroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) would be a better approach here.